# Image is produced in the editor, but not interactively in iPython

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, seaborn

I am using seaborn which is a library based on matplotlib and that enhances some styling features of matplotlib.
If I write the following script in the editor and run it, I get the graph correctly displayed in the image file.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.plt.plot([2,4,8,16],[1,2,3,4])
sns.plot.gcf()
sns.plot.savefig("C:\\in\\Fig1.png")
```

[image]

The problem is that when I write those same lines the interactive way in iPython one by one, I get a blank image file. However, the image is correctly displayed in iPython as soon as I execute the second line:

```
sns.plt.plot([2,4,8,16],[1,2,3,4])
```

So, the question is: why is this happening in the first place, and how do I get an image file with the graph inside it by using iPython?

Comment: I suppose you forgot to configure the inline backend with `%matplotlib inline`

Comment: If you *did* use `%matplotlib inline`, it will close the mpl figure at the end of each cell. So you need to make sure that the call to `savefig()` is in the same cell as where you did the plotting. Or you can store a reference to the figure using `gcf()` in the same cell as your plotting (but you need to use the return value, which your current code doesn't).

Comment: What is "the editor"?